# React component is not reading my css file

Tags: css, reactjs

For some reason, my React Component is not reading my CSS file.  This is the code in my React component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Jumbotron.css';

 class Jumbotron extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="Jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div className="container">
             <h1 className="display-3">{this.props.title}</h1>
             <p className="lead">{this.props.subtitle}</p>
             <p className="lead">{this.props.name}</p>
            </div>

         </div>
       ) 
    }
  }

 export default Jumbotron;
```

Below is my file structure

[image]

The .css file has the following code.

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url(../images/fog-forest-lake-113727.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: the classname is capital `Jumbotron` but in ur css it is all lowercase `jumbotron`...

Comment: Thank you @Yongzhi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - The classname is lowercase in your css, it should be capital. Longer answer below which might be helpful to you.

I would recommend using `styled components'. [Link](https://www.styled-components.com/) is here.

For example your component could look like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StyledWrapper from './styles/wrapper';

class Jumbotron extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
       <StyledWrapper>
           <div className="container">
            <h1 className="display-3">{this.props.title}</h1>
            <p className="lead">{this.props.subtitle}</p>
            <p className="lead">{this.props.name}</p>
           </div>
       </StyledWrapper>
      ) 
   }
 }
```

export default Jumbotron;

And in my `wrapper.js` file I would have the following

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled.div`
  background-image: url(../images/fog-forest-lake-113727.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  color: white;
`;
```